# Azure App Service Plan Scale Out Change Event

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Does Azure expose an event that can be used to trigger an API when scaling out?  For example, let's say we have a rule that will add another instance of a webapp based on some metric.  When the rule condition is met, and Azure adds another instance, can a custom API (or APIM) be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Event Grid to publish events from App Service and the subscriber can be a webhook for example, Also in from the app service plan blade through the scale out menu you will see a tab of Notify. In this tab you will see that you can use webhook as well.